# How to properly export string data with quotes from MySQL to Big Query via csv?

Tags: mysql, csv, google-bigquery

I'm having problems with Big Query when trying to import CSV files from MySQL. These files have been exported with the following options:

```
SELECT <some collunms> 
FROM <my table>
INTO OUTFILE 'export-20160411.csv'
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\\';
```

The problem is how to escape a `"` (double quote) for BQ, here is a CSV example:

```
field01, field02, field03, field04
"xxx \" xxx \\", \N, "xxx", "xxx"
```

which are causing issues. So BQ gives errors like this:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'<project>:bqjob_r7269aea2ac9eae3c_0000015c88a9049d_1': Too many
errors encountered.
Failure details:
- file-00000000: Too many values in row starting at position:
2052615.
```

and this:

```
- mediaupload-snapshot: Error detected while parsing row starting at
position: 561497. Error: Missing close double quote (") character.
```

Finally, my question is: what is the best way to export a CSV so BQ can import it without problems?

Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

The format:

```
field01, field02, field03, field04
"xxx "" xxx \\", \N, "xxx", "xxx"
```

Works, with `""` instead of `\"` inside the string. But I don't know how to export in this way from MySQL.

Comment: Can you share with us an example of the data in your CSV file? Maybe headers and one line as a sample.

Comment: Hi @Will, updated with CSV example

Answer (score 1):

one of the approach is to load your original csv file as if it had just one column (the whole row is just one column)   and than - to do parsing on BigQuery side

In Example below - assume that CSVtable is a table that you loaded with that CSV file as with one column as below:

```sql
oneField     
"xxx "" xxx \\", \N, "xxx", "xxx"
```

So "parsing" can look like below  :

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH CSVtable AS (
  SELECT '''"xxx "" xxx \\\\", \\N, "xxx", "xxx"''' AS oneField
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(oneField)[OFFSET(0)] AS field01,
  SPLIT(oneField)[OFFSET(1)] AS field02,
  SPLIT(oneField)[OFFSET(2)] AS field03,
  SPLIT(oneField)[OFFSET(3)] AS field04  
FROM CSVtable
```

The output of such query is

```sql
field01             field02     field03     field04  
"xxx "" xxx \\"     \N          "xxx"       "xxx"
```